# Create jQuery plugin which not reflect result on same duplicate class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to create jquery plugin which reflect result on only perticular class only not on all same class

**jQuery Plugin**

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {    
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'content'         : 'top'      
    }, options);    
    return this.each(function() {       
      $(this).html(settings.content);
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

**calling plugin**

```
<body>

<div class="toolbar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.toolbar').tooltip({
    content:'this is first'
});
</script>

<div class="toolbar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.toolbar').tooltip({
    content:'this is second'
});
</script>

</body>
```

I expected result:

```
this is first   
this is second
```

But result display:

```
this is second
this is second
```

So how to create plugin which reflect on only particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to tell your plugin that you already did this tag before something like this

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {    
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'content'         : 'top'      
    }, options);    
    return this.not('.tooltiped').each(function() {       
       $(this).html(settings.content);
    }).addClass('tooltiped');
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7m6x/

**UPDATE**

as `Sheikh Heera` suggested if you are only changing the content of the element then this code is enough:

```
  return this.not('.tooltiped').html(settings.content).addClass('tooltiped');
```

Comment: Why the `each` loop and this only works when there is only one element available initially.

Comment: This is enough `return this.not('.tooltiped').html(settings.content).addClass('tooltiped');`

Comment: well it depends if he only wants to change the content ya i agree this is enough but if each item will have different properties then he needs to loop.